# How to print an output from a terminal-only command in a GTK3 window?

Tags: c, gtk3

I have the following GTK3 code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void show(GtkWidget *window, gpointer ptr) {}

void activate(GtkApplication *tmp, gpointer ptr) {

    GtkWidget *scrolled_window;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button_box;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(tmp);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "tmp");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 500);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

    buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);

    view = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer(buffer);

    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(view, 10);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end(view, 10);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(view, 10);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(view, 10);

    gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view), FALSE);
    gtk_text_view_set_cursor_visible(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view), FALSE);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view), GTK_WRAP_WORD);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Show");

    button_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

    gtk_widget_set_halign(button_box, GTK_ALIGN_END);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(button_box, GTK_ALIGN_END);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(button_box, 10);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end(button_box, 10);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(button_box, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(button_box, 10);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button_box, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), view);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button_box), button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(show), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkApplication *tmp;
    int status;

    tmp = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.tmp", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(tmp, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(tmp), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(tmp);

    return status;
}
```

My question is: How do I print the output of a terminal-only command (like "ps aux") in this window after I click "Run"?

I have never written anything with GTK3 so, please, do not point me to https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ as it's a reference and not a tutorial so to use it, one needs to already know some GTK3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far to let such a terminal-only command (aka "program") run from your code?

Comment: I have literally no idea how to even begin.

Comment: Start by researching how to launch other programs. GTK seems to have no support for this. So you have to learn about `fork()` and the `exec()`-family to implement this. Additionally you need to learn about "pipes" for connecting to `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` of the launched process. This is not simple but you will find enough tutorials. Since this has nothing to do with GTK write your experiments as console applications. You will save yourself from a lot of trouble. Then, if you're confident how to use it, add it to your GTK application.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm a bit confused as to what GTK3 is for then. My assumption was that it's used to create GUIs for software written in C or any other language. What's the point of having pretty windows, buttons, drop down menus, etc. when there is no easy way to put external code behind it?

Comment: Well, now it sounds like you have some code producing some kind of results. And you like to have this results in a GUI. This is a completely different issue than "show the output of an external process in my GUI." --- I'm afraid, StackOverflow is not a site providing tutorials or lots of code. You will need to look for a tutorial yourself. There is no easy way to create a complete and well working GUI.

Comment: I've chosen "ps aux" as an example only. In reality, I have about ~200 lines of C code which, when run, lists all the hosts which are up in a given network. I assumed I could have list.c and list-gui.c so you have a choice between typing this command and pressing Enter or having a pretty window with a Run button. The list-gui would use the list binary to do the actual scanning. Should I just incorporate my code into a GTK3 application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202565/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-phearnomore).

Comment: The question is proper when you read my second comment. :) And I have spent a lot of time looking for a tutorial and I have to say that GTK3, in comparison to QT or even GTK2, sucks when it comes to documentation which is not just a reference index.

Comment: OK, so GTK3 might not be the toolbox for beginners. (I wonder where the GTK3 fan boys are… ;-) So we have here a classical [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Maybe even people who like GTK3 don't like it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the above code (which I have modified twice to add what I have learned since I asked my question) with the solution, I'll just paste the difference between it and the final version of the code:

```
 3c3,14
< void show(GtkWidget *window, gpointer ptr) {}
---
> void show(GtkWidget *window, gpointer buffer) {
> 
>   gchar *argv[] = { "/bin/df", "--human-readable", NULL };
>   gchar *output;
>   gchar *error;
> 
>   gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "", -1);
> 
>   g_spawn_sync(NULL, argv, NULL, G_SPAWN_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, &output, &error, NULL, NULL);
> 
>   gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(buffer, output, -1);
> }
56c67
<     g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(show), NULL);
---
>     g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(show), buffer);
```

(thanks to the busybee for valuable pointers!)

The downside of this solution is that the output of the command you run will not be delivered in real time but only when the command finishes. So, if it takes 30 seconds to complete, your GUI will show nothing for 30 seconds and then print everything in one go. I have read that https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSubprocess.html may be the answer but I have not checked it out yet.